# My program produces the wrong output. Why?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

void main() {
float y;
int x;
cout<<"Jep vleren e x-it:"<<endl;
cin>>x;
if (x>=1)
{
    y=(x^3 - 2*x)/(1+x^2);
    cout<<y<<endl;
}
if ((x>-1)&&(x<1))
{
    y = sqrt(1+x^2);
    cout<<y<<endl;
}
if (x<=-1) 
{
    y=x/(1+x^2);
    cout<<y<<endl;
}
_getch();
}
```

I have to calculate the value of y based on x. But there is something wrong - when I input `- 3`, it says `0`. Why?

Comment: How hard is it to post the code here? Less then to make an image of it and host it somewhere I bet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here.

Comment: You're using `^` an unusual number of times.  You don't think it means exponent do you?

Answer (score 2):

you are using ^ XOR operator [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Did you want to use [pow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt5dakze%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) function?

Comment: i wanted to use the pow function but since in school we use  borand c++, we are used to using ^

Comment: @KevinKZ : What? Every Borland compiler I've used uses `^` for xor, just as the language standards mandate...